# How to process multiline data filebeat and skip the first line?

Tags: filebeat, elk

I am new with ELK , I can send all the data from a file but how can I skip the first line ?
is it also possible to sent every 4 set of lines together multiline ?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this, its just the matter of configuring filebeat for multiline messages. For some nice examples, refer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html
and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html

If you already have some skeleton pattern, you can use the Playground to tweak and test your use cases: https://go.dev/play/p/uAd5XHxscu